# Texture a surface with a JPG image

Tags: plotting

My basic problem is how to use JPG and other kinds of image files I already have as a texture to wrap or cover a 3D surface.  I'm not sure if the path is necessary and if so, what's the syntax.

For example, if I wanted to use one of my files to texture

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

How do I do that?

Comment: `Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2},  PlotStyle -> Texture[image]]`?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the earlier suggestion:

```
i = Import@"https://burnersxxx.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/einsteintongue.jpg"

Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Texture[i], 
Mesh -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]